# Can American students do research in Europe with only a bachelor's degree?

Tags: research-process, job-search, international

It's not clear to me, looking over all the various regulations and requirements, how (or even *if*) it is possible for students holding a four-year or five-year bachelor's degree from the US can work at a university as a part-time or full-time researcher. Is this possible? If so, are there specific programs to help set this up? Does it matter which EU country the institution is located? Is there a specific type of visa involved?

(Effectively, I guess this question could be boiled down to: what is the equivalent EU mechanism for a [J-1 visa](http://j1visa.state.gov/), when the student will be engaged in research rather than coursework?)

Comment: Not US, but Canada (hopefully, close enough). The UBC in Vancouver maintains an exchange program with the MPI-FKF in Germany, where they send some of the BSc *candidates* for an 8 month internship to Germany. There they do some of the *research* work (not course work), that a PhD student typically does. I can say from our experience, that we would be very happy to see many of them return for a master's or a PhD, once they acquire their bachelor's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two parts in your question: can someone with a Bachelor from the US get a job from a university or research lab, and what kind of visa such a person would need. For the first question, it's really depending on the university. As for the visa, it depends if it would be for a PhD student, or for a "regular" researcher (i.e. not a student). However, in both cases, the visa application depends on the country, as far as I know, there is no Schengen Research Visa. For instance, for France, there are two types of Visa the person could apply to ([Visa section of the french consulate in Washington](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?rubrique98))

- [The “Skills and Talent” Card visa (Carte Compétences & Talents)](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article519). However, for this one, they say:

  > University graduates should be PhD. Lower graduates will be required to add proof of profesionnal experience in the same field for a minimum of 1 to 3 years (the lower the degree, the longer profesionnal experience expected)
- [Visas for professors and researchers holders of a "convention d’accueil"](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article398). According to this [site](http://www.fnak.fr/dn_Formalites/ES_criteres_eligibilite.html) (in French, I couldn't find an English version), a "convention d'accueil" would basically be the work contract with the university/lab, and the eligibility requirement seems to be a Master degree or equivalent (but it could be the case that a 5-years US Bachelor degree counts as an equivalent to a 5-year French Master degree). As far as I understand, that would be the best option for someone who wants to do her PhD in France.

It would also be possible to apply for a student visa, but I think it's not possible to get a work contract with such a visa. Another solution could be to apply to a:

- [Employer Sponsored visa / OFII](http://www.consulfrance-washington.org/spip.php?article500). There does not seem to be anything specific to research in this case.

So, to sum it up, I don't think there is a unified process to apply for a visa in Europe as a researcher, and each country has its own rules. Note that these visas are not automatically Schengen visa, and I've known the case of some extra-EU students, who obtained a visa in one Schengen country, and were not allowed to travel in other Schengen countries before becoming officially resident of the country.

Comment: Chercheur invité. I stayed in France, during my phd, using a convention d'accueil, as a hired research assistant. As I'm in the process of a J1 now, I'd say it is pretty much the same thing, national differences aside.

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible to work as a researcher in a European University with only a bachelor's degree.**  In many fields, jobs as a research assistant would be pretty accessible to someone with this level of education, if your degree is in a relevant field or you have relevant experience.  You might be able to get a slightly higher level of position if you have a good CV, and there is opportunity for advancement.  However, ultimately it is very hard to advance into higher level academic positions without a PhD.  This only happens in exceptional circumstances.

**However, practically speaking this will be very difficult for someone without the right to work in the EU**, such as a U.S. citizen.  While getting such a job is technically possible (and varies by country), typically it involves the institution sponsoring you.  This involves a lot of effort on their part, and most likely will only happen for higher-level positions.  Also there may be barriers (such as salary level and education level requirements) that prevent you from getting a visa in certain countries, as well.  For example, in the UK you would have to make at least £35,000 or have a PhD level job to get the relevant visa.  **In short, unless you have some unique, in-demand skills, this is unlikely to be a real option.**

**If you want to work as a researcher in Europe, consider studying for a higher degree in Europe.**  The barrier to entry is much lower for this; visas can be obtained relatively easily, and institutions provide a lot of support to help you.  This need not be a PhD, you could just do a one year masters' degree.  Depending on the country, you may be able to work while studying on a student visa.  You also may have an easier path to transition to a work visa.  In any case, the connections you make, and the additional education you get, should help.